# Procdump to capture service hangs

Tags: windows-services, dump, sysinternals, procdump

I am using below command to obtain procdump dump file when a service hangs but it not doing anything

```
procdump -64 -ma -t -n 2 -s 10 MyProcess.exe C:\myprocess.exe.dmp
```

Comment: "Not doing anything" means, after you press Enter, nothing happens and procdump does not start? Please deescribe your problem in more detail.

Comment: My guess is that a) you should use `-x C:\myprocess.exe.dmp MyProcess.exe` and b) check whether you have write permissions on C:\

Comment: still no result,

Comment: i am monitoring one service,noticed that its hanging or failing sometimes and its only working once i restarted it ..i am not sure how procdump can help me here   @ThomasWeller

Answer (score 1):

It's not doing anything because you didn't tell it to.  Your parameters tell procdump to take two 64bit full-memory dumps (-64 -ma -n 2) 10 seconds apart (-s 10) when the process terminates (-t), not hangs.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure procdump can help you here.  The hang parameter (-h) triggers when the app "does not respond window messages for at least 5 seconds" -- but a service has no window, and so presumably would never trigger this.